# Perform system import/export command line artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I need to know how can I perform a sysyem export/import by command line by artifactory.

Is there any command that will do this task ?

My version of artifactory is 7.29

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [Import/Export REST API's](http://jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-IMPORT&EXPORT) for this purpose, like below,
Export full system:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST https://myartifactory/api/export/system -d @export.json

Import full system:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST https://myartifactory/api/import/system -d @export.json

Also, refer to this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/) on migrating the Arifactory via system import/export and replacing the UI operations with the REST APIs.

Comment: Hi @muhammed kashif , when i enter the command with the ip of my artifactory, it gaves me an error 443

Comment: what error? I do not see any error, otherwise try the curl without https but with http